# Perl - Checking for file from array exists in directory

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the contents of an `ls` command in Linux out to the command line using an array. Only issue I'm getting is, that when the files are looked over using an `if` statement, it seems to be only searching in the PWD of the script and not the path specified.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
my $directory = $ARGV[0];
chomp (my @files = `ls -a $directory`);
my @plainfiles;
my @directories;
if (-f $_) {
    push (@plainflies, $_);
}
elsif (-d $_) {
    push (@directories, $_);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in using a glob: `my @files = <$ARGV[0]/*>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check `"$directory/$_"` instead of just `$_`.

Secondly, File::Slurp::read_dir() can do the same job for you without calling external command and can also filter out ".", ".." etc. Check [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#read_dir) for details.

Comment: @TLP: Thanks. I put correct link to `read_dir` but incorrect name `read_file`. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

`ls directory` returns the files inside the directory, that is only the file names and not file name prefixed with the directory name. Apart from that using a shell command to get the contents of the file is just overkill. Try instead using opendir and readdir together with map to get the files prefixed with the directory:

```
 opendir(my $dh,$directory);
 my @files = map { "$directory/$_" } grep { !m{^\.\.?$} } readdir($dh);
```

Or you might use glob to match specific files (like no files starting with "." in this case):

```
 my @files = glob("$directory/*");
```